# angular 2 app-root not loading when running

Tags: node.js, angular

I followed the instruction from here: https://angular.io/cli

I executed the following lines with no route option:

```
ng new test-test-projectthree
ng serve
```

I am suppose to see everything from app.component.html ? However, I just see an empty page. The index page is display, but the root component is not loading (I do not see anything from root component html file).

I am running everything on Red Hat linux 7 and I am connecting to it using mobaXterm.

I am testing it on firefox ESR 38.6.1 and I see no error in firefox console.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestProjectthree</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'test-projectthree';
    }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to dz!
  </h1>
</div>
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'test-projectthree'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('test-projectthree');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to test-projectthree!');
  });
});
```

console output:

```
ng serve
 10% building 3/3 modules 0 activeℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html                                                                                                                                                            chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 7.28 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 251 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.81 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-07-30T21:01:50.970Z - Hash: b54b63db5003df7b9b19 - Time: 15924ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
SystemMessageCache: initATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
1565203202194   addons.repository       WARN    Search failed when repopulating cache
1565203202731   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest was not valid XML
```

Anything suggestion on what I am doing wrong? 
I don't see any error when I run angular using the ng serve command (except for "Search failed when repopulating cache", but I don't think that is the problem) and I don't see any error in the firefox console. Since I am also new to angular 2, I am not sure what I can do to solve this issue right now.

Comment: There are no errors.....open localhost:4200 and you should see the output....what do you see?

Comment: If I add some text to index.html, it does get displayed, so I think localhost:4200 is working. However, nothing from app.component.html is showing.

Comment: Do you have any custom css? What is in the browser consol error log?

Comment: What browser and version of the browser you were using?

Comment: I am running everything on Red Hat Linux 7 from window using mobaXterm. I am using Firefox ESR 38.6.1.

Comment: When I press f12 to bring up my firefox console, it is empty (no error at all).

Comment: I left my app.component.css as empty for now.

Comment: Can you try it in an other browser? Make a stackblitz demo projet and put all your code so it could tested inside it. If it works there should be something from your envirnment. Please share the demo link

Comment: Try running `ng build --prod` as it can often highlight errors that `ng serve` does not.

Comment: I tried ng build --prod and still dont see any error.

Comment: However, when I did ng serve --host=testdev1 and then opened it from my chrome on my window machine, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comment, you seem to have some *localhost* configuration on your system that clashes with Angular, so you have to define another valid host to run Angular's development server.

Some useful parameters to configure `ng s` (from the [Official Angular Guide](https://angular.io/cli/serve)):

> `--host=host`: Host to listen on (default: `localhost`)
>
> `--open=true|false`: Opens the url in default browser (default: `false`)
>
> `--port`: Port to listen on (default: `4200`)

Comment: This answer is valid, fixed same issue i was facing launching angular application

Answer (score -2):

I found this link very usefull:

by adding HttpClientModule to imports in src/app/app.module.ts my problem solved

https://malcoded.com/posts/why-angular-not-works/